# Swift: Mysterious constraint appearing

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to create a list of alarms in a UICollectionView, where an "on" alarm has an image (alarmImg) and time label (alarmLbl), and an "off" alarm has an image and blank time label. I'd like the "off" alarm image to be centered while the "on" alarm image has an offset to account for the label.

This is my code in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, where cell is a dequeued cell and alarmLbls is a String array of alarm times.

```
cell.alarmLbl.text = alarmLbls[indexPath.row]     

if alarmLbls[indexPath.row] == "" {
    cell.alarmImg.image = UIImage(named: "alarm_off")
    let alarmImgYConstraintOff = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.alarmImg, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cell.mainView, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    alarmImgYConstraintOff.active = true
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
}
else {
    cell.alarmImg.image = UIImage(named: "alarm_on")
    let alarmImgYConstraintOn = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.alarmImg, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cell.mainView, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 0.75, constant: 0)
    alarmImgYConstraintOn.active = true
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Initial layout looks fine, but when I call `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths` on the cells containing "on" alarms, I get a constraint error indicating that the "off" constraint is being applied, in which case the "on" constraint breaks and the images shift to the center. The first `if` block doesn't seem to be getting called for these cells, though, according to print tests (only for "off" cells reloading from off the screen), and this is the only place I've set these constraints.

I've tried just about every iteration of solutions I can think of:

1. Forcing `alarmImgYConstraintOff.active = false`
2. Setting a center constraint via IB and turning it off programmatically
3. Switching the "on" block to the `if` statement
4. Changing `else` to `else if`

Setting the "on" constraint's priority to something higher than the "off" constraint's priority only makes all of the "off" images shift upward upon reloading instead. For some reason, though, on the fourth reload, the images shift back to their original centered (correct) position.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong here?

**EDIT: Code for turning undesired constraints off**

```
cell.alarmLbl.text = alarmLbls[indexPath.row]

let alarmImgYConstraintOff = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.alarmImg, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cell.mainView, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0) 
let alarmImgYConstraintOn = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.alarmImg, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cell.mainView, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 0.75, constant: 0)    

if alarmLbls[indexPath.row] == "" {
    cell.alarmImg.image = UIImage(named: "alarm_off")
    alarmImgYConstraintOn.active = false
    alarmImgYConstraintOff.active = true
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
}
else {
    cell.alarmImg.image = UIImage(named: "alarm_on")
    alarmImgYConstraintOff.active = false
    alarmImgYConstraintOn.active = true
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Initial layout looks good, as before, but I'm still getting layout breaks as soon as I reload an "on" cell (save for the very first reload). E.g. The second reload of an "on" cell breaks, as do subsequent reloads of all "on" and "off" cells (though no visible difference is seen for "off" cells); however, if I reload an "off" cell first, nothing breaks until I reload an "on" cell.

Comment: When you turn one constraint on you should turn the other one off.  If you tried that and it didn't work then you likely didn't do it correctly.  Can you post the code from that attempt?

Comment: Edited question to include new code and results! Still no dice, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

When you are setting `alarmImgYConstraintOff.active = true`, you are merely adding a second constraint to what you already have. Try removing the unwanted constraint first before applying a new one. This should clear the issue.

Comment: I've posted my code with your suggestion, but I'm still seeing issues (see edited question).

Comment: I recently did a similar thing in my app involving a moving view. I did it by changing the value of the constraint.constant rather than adding and removing constraints and had no issues. Maybe give that a try?

Comment: I've just tried it with one constraint, making the .constant = 0 in the "off" block and -10 in the "on" block. "On" cells reload with layout breaks, though the images remain where they're supposed to be. "Off" cells reload with layout breaks shifting them to the -10 position. It looks like the problem again starts as soon as I reload an "on" cell. Interestingly, though, for one (but not all) of the "off" cells, the image shifts back to the correct position on the fourth reload?

Answer (score 0):

Try saving a reference to the same constraint and just change the .multiplier to either 1 or 0.75, it's not necessary to change the entire constraint just to change that.

Comment: It looks like constraint multipliers are read-only properties, so you can't modify them by setting the .multiplier to something different.